# How to check your wallet's share of the liquidity pool (uniswap or quickswap) using web3

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py, uniswap

How can i check my wallet's share of the uniswap/quickswap liquidity pool using web3py ?

The objective is to check what is my indirect token A and token B position and also if possible the rewards pending for my wallet ? While debank can help, I just want to learn how to query using python directly.

In adding liquidity to the liquidity pool, my wallet sends token A and token B to the smart contract address of the liquidity pool and also interact with the router contract, and my wallet also receives a "uniswap v2 token"

I tried querying my wallet address with the balanceof function of the smart contract address but there was an error ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your share of liquidity pool is:

```
Your LP token amount / total LP token supply
```

[Here are some library functions Python and Uniswap v2 for working with DeFi](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/index.html). You can use [fetch_erc20_details](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/api/_autosummary/eth_defi.token.fetch_erc20_details.html#eth_defi.token.fetch_erc20_details) to get the total supply of LP token or a pair contract.